Upload works on all devices but ios
I'm working on an online platform with react and jango.
There is a form for tickets and users are able to attach a file.
attachment works perfect in pc and android but when I try to attach a file in ios it doesn't work and message will send without attachment.
here is input tag in send ticket form :
<input
      type="file"
      accept=".jpg,.png,.pdf,.jpeg,.mp4,.zip,.rar"
      id="attach"
      className="w-0 h-0 opacity-0"
      {...register("attachment")}
      onChange={(e) => fileNameHandler(e)}
/>

I use console.log method to compare form objects.
here is form object for pc :

and this is form object for ios :

as you can see, symbols(symbol.iterator and symbol.toStringTag) are undefined. what are they used for? and do you ahve any idea what's the problem ?
